# Using the Feed Import module, I can not map for “address field”

Tags: feeds, importing-exporting, entities

I use the [Feed Import](http://drupal.org/project/feed_import)" to import nodes. The other fields were OK, but I cannot map the address field provided by the [Address Field](http://drupal.org/project/addressfield) module.

I edited the feed, used "Enter field name," and set to "FIELD_CONTACT_ADDRESS: LOCALITY," but it doesn't work.

I also tried "FIELD_CONTACT_ADDRESS:LOCALITY," "FIELD_CONTACT_ADDRESS_LOCALITY," "FIELD_CONTACT_ADDRESS-LOCALITY," but they don't work.

Answer (score 4):

You may need to set your country.  I've seen feeds import the data into the tables, but nothing displays because there is no country set.